# Resizing a NumPy array that's a DICOM image - Resize or Rescale?

Tags: python, image-processing, scikit-image

I'm trying to make my image dimensions smaller to process in a model.

I'm using `skimage.transform.resize()` and `skim age.transform.rescale()` and can't decide between the two.

I definitely need to maintain the data in the image. I'm afraid that I'm either deleting or adding data.

This is my code:

`resized_img = resize(image, (200, 200), anti_aliasing=True)`

`resized_img = rescale(image, 0.39, anti_aliasing=True)`

Please let me know what I can do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looking at the [Rescale, resize and downscale documentation](https://scikit-image.org/docs/stable/auto_examples/transform/plot_rescale.html), rescale and resize do almost the same thing.

The only question is do you want to size of your new image to be a factor of the original size?  Or do you want the new image to be of a fixed size?  It just depends on your particular application.

Comment: I'm just worried about modifying my array in a way that it loses data. I'm not sure if that's happening. Is it?

Comment: If you're reducing the size of an image, you are losing information.  No two ways about it.  A 200x200 image will not have as much information as a 400x400.  Doing anti-aliasing will remove artifacting, so that the low frequency information is preserved, though.  It's the best you can do.

Comment: Related to losing information - if you're working on a dicom image, is your image still in the bit depth it was acquired in (likely 16-bit), or are you working on an 8-bit version (or even worse jpg version of).  ...If you're worried about losing data, you'd be much better to be worried about using only an 8-bit version, rather than a scaling effect

Comment: That's a lot of help. Thank you